# which is better in terms of performance, one constraint layout or three linear layouts?

Tags: android, performance

I come across these situations when I have to choose between using one constraint layout vs using a combination of linear and frame layouts. Let's say it's only 3 linear layouts vs one constraint layout, what is better in terms of performance ?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of performance, one **`ConstraintLayout`** will certainly be more optimal than 3 **`LinearLayouts`**. The logic is pretty simple - 1 **`ViewGroup`** is easier to be rendered and maintained than 3. Plus, feature wise **`ConstraintLayout`** will give you more size classes coverage than 3 **`LinearLayouts`**.

Answer (score 0):

The question has the answer in it... Obviously less views will be better for the performance. But, besides the obvious 1, 3 difference - The actual performance of a `ConstraintLayout` is better than a `LinearLayout`.